# Adding "on hover pause" to slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I was wondering is it possible to add in a "on hover (for slide) pause" to the following?

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#myController").jFlow({  
        slides: "#slides",  // the div where all your sliding divs are nested in  
        controller: ".jFlowControl", // must be class, use . sign  
        slideWrapper : "#jFlowSlide", // must be id, use # sign  
        selectedWrapper: "jFlowSelected",  // just pure text, no sign  
        width: "610px",  // this is the width for the content-slider  
        height: "235px",  // this is the height for the content-slider  
        duration: 400,  // time in miliseconds to transition one slide  
        prev: ".jFlowPrev", // must be class, use . sign  
        next: ".jFlowNext" // must be class, use . sign  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

I was following the tutorial found at http://www.webdesignbooth.com/step-by-step-to-create-content-slider-using-jflow-a-minimalist-jquery-plugin/ on creating a slider. I was going to utilize this in a wordpress theme, and I would love to have a "hover", so users could pause the slide to click the link.

Answer (score 1):

Download the file http://www.dlocc.com/downloads/jquery.flow.1.2.auto.pause.zip and replace with jquery.flow.1.2.js and you are done. It will pause on mouse hover.